# Pass data through call stack without method modification

Tags: java, algorithm

I've got some crazy task, that sounds like mission impossible. I need to pass some data through stack of methods, which I can't modify (can modify only the last one). Example:

```
SomeData someData; //not passed in method1
obj1.method1(...);
```

here is obj1 class code

```
obj1 {
    someReturnClass method1(...) {
        ...
        obj2.method2(...);
        ...
    }
}
```

obj2 and method2 call some more methods, before they get to objN.methodM(). It can even be run in separate thread (so, ThreadLocal won't help). I need to access someData inside methodM, which is not passed through this stack as parameter.

I've got some concepts to get it through exception and double running methodM, but it looks ugly.

Do you have any ideas, how to pass someData to methodM()?

Comment: To be clear: do you mean that you need to access a local variable inside a method activation, of a method which you can't change, but which you know exists lower on the stack?

Comment: Basically, you need some sort of (relatively) static data.  This could be a "singleton", an instance field in some commonly addressable object, a thread-local variable, or a handful of other things.

Comment: Yes, I thought about some singleton. But several such stacks ending on my methods may be ran simultaneously.

Comment: Can you, or can you not, alter the code at the site where `someData` is created?  (This is in effect what @Marcin is asking above.)  If you cannot, you are stuck.  If you can, you can simply tuck a reference to it into a global variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found solution:

Create JAAS Subject

```
Subject subject = new Subject();
```

Put data somewhere in subject's principals or credentials:

```
subject.getPublicCredentials().add(new String("Trololo"));
```

Get this subject and it's data anywhere you need (works even in another thread):

```
Subject subject = Subject.getSubject(AccessController.getContext());
System.out.println(subject.getPublicCredentials());
```

It won't work only in one case: thread started before subject was created.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't smuggle access any other way -- e.g. by adding a reference to `SomeData` into some other object that *is* passed through the call stack -- then you will eventually have to use a global variable.  This is of course a poor design, but nothing else is possible given your constraints.

You mentioned in a comment that you may have several calls to your method "active" (is it recursive, or do you have multiple threads?)  In that case, you will need to have a global collection instead, and have some way of inferring which element of the collection to select from the data that *is* passed through the call stack.

Comment: In my weird case this method fits best. Thanks for this simple idea, I didn't even think about it.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you need to access a local variable inside a method activation, of a method which you can't change, but which you know exists lower on the stack.

The obvious thing here is to work with the Java Debugging Architecture: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/index.html

This will allow you to examine the stacks of all threads.

Comment: For JPDA jvm needs to be ran in debug mode. That's a big problem for my case.

Comment: @Oroboros102 So, you can't modify the code, and you can't run it in debug mode? In that case, you can't do it.

Comment: What about a global variable?  They aren't illegal, just immoral :)

Comment: @j_random_hacker How does he get data into the variable? He can't modify the code which currently has the data.

Comment: So he can't even modify the site where `someData` is created? In that case he is indeed stuck. But I see he (unhelpfully) hasn't actually confirmed or denied your question about this yet.

Comment: @j_random_hacker global variable may be overwritten, if another method...N stack is ran in parallel.

Comment: @Oroboros102: Not if you use a global *collection* of objects, and can uniquely infer which element in the collection to work with using other information that is passed through the call stack.  See my answer.